# jqGrid not showing my data?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

This is how my data is structured:

```
[
  {
    "email": "ww@ww.com",
    "name": "ww",
    "password": "qLfsebHMKv7dNgExtR",
    "active": false,
    "role": "admin",
    "createdAt": "2013-10-22T11:48:32.719Z",
    "updatedAt": "2013-10-22T11:48:32.719Z",
    "id": "52666610a6a311308b000001"
  },
  {
    "email": "qq@qq.com",
    "name": "QQ",
    "password": "twfubGHoQkYDVup",
    "active": true,
    "role": "expert",
    "createdAt": "2013-10-22T11:38:47.578Z",
    "updatedAt": "2013-10-22T11:38:47.578Z",
    "id": "526663c788101c9f89000001"
  }
]
```

and this is my js:

```
$(function () {
    $('#list').jqGrid({
      url: '/api/v1/users',
      datatype: 'json',
      mtype: 'GET',
      colNames: ['id','email','name', 'password', 'active','role','createdAt','updatedAt'],
      colModel: [
      { name: 'id', width: 80 },
      { name: 'email', width: 80 },
      { name: 'name', width: 80, align: 'right' },
      { name: 'password', width: 80, align: 'right' },
      { name: 'active', width: 80, align: 'right' },
      { name: 'role', width: 80, align: 'right' },
      { name: 'createdAt', width: 80, align: 'right' },
      { name: 'updatedAt', width: 80, sortable: false }
      ],
      jsonReader: { 
        repeatitems: false,
        id: "id",
        root: function (obj) { return obj; },
        page: function (obj) { return 1; },
        total: function (obj) { return 1; },
        records: function (obj) { return obj.length; }
      },
      pager: '#pager',
      rowNum: 10,
      rowList: [10, 20, 30],
      sortname: 'invid',
      sortorder: 'desc',
      viewrecords: true,
      gridview: true,
      autoencode: true,
      caption: 'My first grid'
    }); 
  });
```

I could not get that to work at all, even worse that disable the whole page!.
What am I missing here?

---

**Update 1:**
I added:

```
  loadComplete: function (data) {
    console.log("OK");
    console.log(data);
  },
  loadError: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    console.log('HTTP status code: ' + jqXHR.status + 'n' +
    'textStatus: ' + textStatus + 'n' +
    'errorThrown: ' + errorThrown);
    console.log('HTTP message body (jqXHR.responseText): ' + 'n' + jqXHR.responseText);
  }
```

*loadComplete* always returns *OK*, however, *data* is an empty array *[]*.

---

**Update 2:**
I inspected the request jqGrid sends and it apear it appends this to my API:

```
/api/v1/users?_search=false&nd=1384254700817&rows=20&page=1&sidx=&sord=asc
```

When I hit this url it does return that empaty array. Any idea how to change this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disabling you Page when Grid is loading/loaded means there is some CSS Problem.

First, Check whether you have added ui.jqgrid.css . The blocking may happen in the case of not inlcuding it.

Are u able to hit URL?

The another mistake in your grid is: `Sortname` . you have specified '`invid'`  which is  an invalid column name according to your Column Model.

So, Correct it. If you are using latest version of Jqgrid. There is no need to include following code:

```
jsonReader: { 
        repeatitems: false,
        id: "id",
        root: function (obj) { return obj; },
        page: function (obj) { return 1; },
        total: function (obj) { return 1; },
        records: function (obj) { return obj.length; }
      },
```

You can Just Ignore above code.. Jqgrid will take care of it.

If you need to user Sorting and Paging, then you need to Specify `LoadOnce:true`.

This will make your grid data as local and sorting and paging works .

If you are not Specifying , then you need to take care of sorting,filtering and paging.

Hopw this helps...

```
**UPdated:**


[
  {
    "email": "ww@ww.com",
    "name": "ww",
    "password": "qLfsebHMKv7dNgExtR",
    "active": "false",
    "role": "admin",
    "createdAt": "2013-10-22T11:48:32.719Z",
    "updatedAt": "2013-10-22T11:48:32.719Z",
    "id": "52666610a6a311308b000001"
  },
  {
    "email": "qq@qq.com",
    "name": "QQ",
    "password": "twfubGHoQkYDVup",
    "active":"true",
    "role": "expert",
    "createdAt": "2013-10-22T11:38:47.578Z",
    "updatedAt": "2013-10-22T11:38:47.578Z",
    "id": "526663c788101c9f89000001"
  }
]
```

Comment: Still no data! I was missing ui.jqgrid.css so now the page is not disabled any more, but still no data :(

Comment: Check what is the exacet response you are getting using any IE tool/FireBug.Are you sure you are getting appropriate JSOn response?

Comment: Every thing seems fine..the only problem could the json response  that is being recieved. It should be in Valid JSON format.

Comment: In the above JSON, the value for active field is being mentioned as boolean. Butm,i guess in JSON every thing is a string. Can you try my updated answer?

Comment: The problem turned out to be that jqGrid appends parameters to my GET URL. Would really appreciate it if you can have a look at my question regarding this here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19988881/how-to-amend-the-defulte-jqgrid-url-prameters