# How to amend the default jqGrid url parameters?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

jqGrid append this to my url:

```
?_search=false&nd=1384254700817&rows=20&page=1&sidx=&sord=asc
```

How to disable that and not suffixing it to my URL?

Comment: this should help ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126712/unable-to-disable-sorting-in-jqgrid#answer-8198012

Comment: @Xander really sorry but what sorting got to do with my question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [prmNames](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aoptions) to rename or to remove parameters which jqGrid sends to the server. For example you can use

```
prmNames: { search: null, nd: null, rows: null, page: null, sort: null, order: null }
```

to remove `?_search=false&nd=1384254700817&rows=20&page=1&sidx=&sord=asc` part of the URL.

Alternatively you can use `postData: ""` to remove *all* parameters.